# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when parse exact

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime, cultureinfo

I get the following exception when converting to DateTime:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

---

```
lbl_RequestDate.Text = "13/2/2013";

CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
string[] format = provider.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
Follow.RequestDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lbl_RequestDate.Text, format, provider, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: What is the type of Follow.RequestDate? And what culture are you runnig? Is MM/DD/YYYY valid?

Comment: What _is_ the `CurrentCulture` (`provider`)? In some cultures the date separator string is distinct from `"/"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use thje format `d/M/yyyy`, Notice the single `M` used for the month.

```
Follow.RequestDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lbl_RequestDate.Text, "d/M/yyyy", provider, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

The method: `provider.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()` returns almost 155 formats, but none of them *(from your current culture seems to)* supports format `d/M/yyyy` that is why you are getting the exception. If your date has Month as `13/02/2013` then the formats returned by the method would work since the closest format is `dd/MM/yyyy` in the formats array.

Comment: You: _none of them supports format `d/M/yyyy`_ Well, that depends strongly on the provider. For example `en-SG` (English (Singapore)), `pt-BR` (Portuguese (Brazil)), `el-GR` (Greek (Greece)), and many others, do support `"d/M/yyyy"`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help  :

```
DateTime.ParseExact("13/2/2013","d/M/yyyy",CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None );
```

notice :

```
d is for Day  (01 is also acceptable)
M is for Month (11 is also acceptable)
```

Comment: I'll be glad to know why this downvote. although it is correct.

Comment: Maybe because you wrote "13/2/2013" directly into the method? 
I don't know, it's right though. +1

Comment: Why would you use the `en-US` culture? Just because it happens to match the date format presented in the question? For me the other answers are superior.

Comment: @DanielKelley `"13/2/2013"` dos not match the `en-US` date format.the en-Us here is also acceptable . just change the order  - which is why parseExact exists.

Comment: @RoyiNamir So then why include a specific culture at all? If you wanted to show that culture is invalid when supplying a format to `ParseExact` then why not say so?

Comment: @DanielKelley If you happen to like Anglo-Americans, it's fine. Also, the culture `es-US` has the same `DateSeparator` string, but maybe you don't like Spanish language as much?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Sorry, that comment really makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @DanielKelley I meant maybe Royi Namir likes Anglo-Americans since he chose their specific culture. As long as you choose a culture that uses the Gregorian calendar, the most important thing to be aware of is the `DateSeparator` string of that culture. The slashes in `"d/M/yyyy"` are translated into that string. If you want literal slashes that are not translated, _escape_ the slashes. Most of the time I would choose a culture that is relevant to the users of the application, or choose the `InvariantCulture` (which happens to honor anglophones as well).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I think we agree then. My issue is the inclusion of a specific culture when it doesn't seem necessary - especially given the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
Follow.RequestDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lbl_RequestDate.Text, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Most of the time, when you want single `M`, you also want single `d`, so: `"d/M/yyyy"`.

Answer (score 1):

[`DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aszyst2c.aspx) method returns on my machine (`tr-TR` Culture) 29 format but none of these support `d/M/yyyy` date format, that's why you are getting `FormatException`.

But in my culture `DateSeparator` is `.` so I can't *exactly* solve this problem using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` but when I use **Egypt** cultureinfo (it's wrote on your profile) `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-EG")` this code works without any error;

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ar-EG");
string[] format = provider.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("13/02/2013", format, provider, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

*Unfortunatly* your your all datetime pattern doesn't support `d/M/yyyy` format.

[image]

<strike>*Unfortunatly*, changing this string to `13/02/2013` doesn't solve this problem because as I said on before, my all formats (in `tr-TR` Culture) doesn't support `dd/MM/yyyy` format either.</strike>

My humble advice is here, list all your datetime patterns and check manually if your string is recognized format with this datetime pattern like;

```
string[] format = provider.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
foreach (var f in format)
{
    ///
}
```

[image]

Comment: When the provider is the `tr-TR` culture, the `DateSeparator` string is `"."`. So any non-escaped slash in the format string, like the slashes in `"d/M/yyyy"`, translates to a period. So this should parse: `DateTime.ParseExact("13.2.2013", "d/M/yyyy", new CultureInfo("tr-TR"));`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You are right. I missed that. Will update answer.